# Como utlizar el metodo push para agregar un obj a un atributo de arrays de objetos

Tags: javascript, array, typescript, poo

me encuentro con duda estoy utilizando dos clase de objetos, una que Movie que es Objt Peliculas , y otro una clase llamada Imbd, que tiene como atributo que es array de Movies , lo que intento es escribir en un fichero json los datos leerlos y después pedir por consola que usuario agregue una película hacer push.

La classe movie:

```
class Movie {
    title:string;
    releseYear:number;
    actors:number;
    nacionality:string;
    director:string;
    writert:string;
    lenguage:string;
    mainCharacterName:string;
    produced:string;
    disttributor:string;
    genre:string;
    constructor(title:string,releseYear:number,nacionality:string){
        this.title=title;
        this.releseYear=releseYear;
        this.nacionality=nacionality;
    }
}
export{Movie};
```

La classe movie es para generar las peliculas.
La classe Imbd:

```
import {Movie} from "./Movie";
const fs = require('fs');

class Imdb{
    public movie:Movie[];

    constructor(movie:Movie[]){
        this.movie = movie;
    }
   public  escribirEnFicheroJson(nombreFichero:string):void{
        let rawdata = fs.readFileSync("pepito"+".json");
        let data =  JSON.parse(rawdata);
        data = JSON.stringify(data,null,2);
        
        fs.writeFile(nombreFichero+".json", data, (err) => {
            if (err) throw err;
            console.log('Los datos se encrito en el archivo');
        });
    }
    public obtenerIntanciaIMDB(nombreFichero:string){
        let rawdata = fs.readFileSync(nombreFichero+".json");
        let data =  JSON.parse(rawdata);
        let imb = new Imdb(data);
        return imb;
    }
}
export{Imdb};
```

La classe Main:

```
import {Movie} from "./Movie";
import {Professional} from "./Professional";
import {Imdb} from "./Imdb";
var prompt = require('prompt-sync')();
//import { readFileSync } from 'fs';
const fs = require('fs');
let pelicula;

let cent = new Movie("5Centimentros",2021,"Asiatica");
let Conbat = new Movie("Conbat",2021,"Americana");
let whatif = new Movie("whatif",2021,"Americana");

let array = [cent,Conbat,whatif];
let f = new Imdb(array);
f.escribirEnFicheroJson("finalobject");
var n = prompt('Como se llama la Pelicula? ');
var n2 = prompt('En que año se hizo la Pelicula?');
var n3 = prompt('En que pais se hizo la Pelicula?');

let nuevapelicula = new Movie(n,n2,n3);

let obj = f.obtenerIntanciaIMDB("pepito");
console.log(obj);

obj.push(nuevapelicula);
```

El principal problema que tengo es que a la hora de recuperar el archivo json , con los datos de array de arriba, no  puedo utlizar el metodo de los array push para agregar la pelicula en ultima posicion de atributo movie de la classe Imbd,
como lo podria hacer
Muchas gracias por la ajuda

Comment: Pero es que es que `obj` no es un array, es un objeto. No puedes hacer `push`. Tu método `obtenerIntanciaIMDB` te devuelve un objeto de tipo `Imdb`, no es un arreglo.

Comment: Pero como lo hago para agregar un nuevo  objeto a ese array sin eliminar el otro